# Extracting xml attribute data with Java xstream

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I have an cucumber xml report and I want to extract the information in the attributes of the opening xml tag

the XML report looks like this

```
<testsuite failures="" name="" skipped="" tests="">
  <testcase>
     <skipped>
      more tags but they are not relevant 
     </skipped>
  </testcase>
</testsuite>
```

I want to be able to take the information from the testsuite attributes save them as java object so that I can put them in an email body that will be sent out to a mailing list.

the information provided in the testsuite xml tag is all I care about.

what would be the best way to approach this? I was creating a Testsuite class,
annotating variables for the attributes I want with @XStreamAsAttribute and getting them that
way but I am fairly unsure if this is correct.

I have no experience with xstream so trying to go with what information I can find online.

Update - have an issue in the function where I extract the xml attributes, only the last attribute name and value are being returned.

```
public String extractXMLReportAttributes() {
        String messageBody = "";
    
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            Attr a = (Attr) nl.item(i);
            messageBody = String.format("%s: %s", a.getName(), a.getValue());
            System.out.println(messageBody);
        }
        return messageBody;

    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use XPath to directly extract the attribute values compared to detouring via Java objects?

Comment: @forty-two I am not aware of what you mean? would your suggestion be a simpler and easier approach? this is my first time doing anything like this so I am open to any and all suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is to grab some attribute values, you may also consider using [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) since it is very intuitive and straight forward. Jsoup is a HTML parser but is also capable of parsing XML. Using Jsoup your code could look like something like:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.parser.Parser;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        final File file = new File("/path/to/your/file.xml");
        Document document = Jsoup.parse(file, "UTF-8", "", Parser.xmlParser());

        Element testsuite = document.selectFirst("testsuite");
        
        String failures   = testsuite.attr("failures");
        String name       = testsuite.attr("name");
        String skipped    = testsuite.attr("skipped");
        String tests      = testsuite.attr("tests");

        System.out.printf("Failures: %s, Name: %s, Skipped: %s, Tests: %s", failures, name, skipped, tests);
    }
}
```

Add [maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup/1.16.2) dependency or download jar:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
    <version>1.16.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Selector syntax can be found here : [Selector](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html)

Answer (score 0):

An example using Java and XPath:

```
    Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newDefaultInstance()
            .newDocumentBuilder()
            .parse(...);
    XPath xp = XPathFactory.newDefaultInstance().newXPath();
    
    // Get values of known attributes
    System.out.println("Name: " + xp.evaluate("/testsuite/@name", doc));
    System.out.println("Tests: " + xp.evaluate("/testsuite/@tests", doc));
    System.out.println("Failures: " + xp.evaluate("/testsuite/@failures", doc));
    System.out.println("Skipped: " + xp.evaluate("/testsuite/@skipped", doc));

    // Get name and values of arbitrary attributes
    NodeList nl = (NodeList) xp.evaluate("/testsuite/@*", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for (int i=0; i < nl.getLength(); ++i) {
        Attr a = (Attr) nl.item(i);
        System.out.printf("%s: %s\n", a.getName(), a.getValue());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply, I have been reading documentation relating to xpath after your earlier comment and it seems like it would be a simpler approach to my problem.

Comment: I have a question I have created a function for looping through the nodelist, I have posted the code in the main section, I am trying to extract these values to be used in a javaMail email body

the problem is when I call this function I only get the last name and value from the list?
when I print the messageBody in the for loop I have all the attributes and values I want.

Comment: Well, you're overwriting messageBody on every loop ;)

Comment: I realised that not long after posting this, been staring at the code for too long :(